# WPF Panel to allow rows, with the top being collapseable

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml

I am trying to create a WPF Control that shows two RichTextBoxes.  One on top of the other, each taking equal space.

But when the top one does not have anything in it, then I need the bottom one to fill in that space.

I tried using a Grid, but I can't get it to work right.

These are the row definitions I have tried:

```
<Grid>  
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
     <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>

  <RichTextBox Grid.Row="0" />
  <RichTextBox Grid.Row="1" />     
</Grid>
```

When both rows are showing the top one has the height of the in it (not 50/50 split).

```
<Grid>  
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
     <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
     <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>

  <RichTextBox Grid.Row="0" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
  <RichTextBox Grid.Row="1" />     
</Grid>
```

When the top row is collapsed, the bottom row does not expand to fill its space.

```
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
     <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
     <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

Using this or adding a MinHeight to the bottom row causes the container to be unbounded.  So that I Don't get a scroll bar for my bottom RichTextBox.

**Is there any way to get two controls to stack on top of each other, and *equally* fill the available space?**  (While allowing one to collapse)

Note: I am not tied to a Grid.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do it:

```
<UniformGrid Columns="1">  
  <RichTextBox />
  <RichTextBox />     
</UniformGrid>
```

And for collapsed:

```
<UniformGrid Columns="1">  
  <RichTextBox Visibility="Collapsed" />
  <RichTextBox />     
</UniformGrid>
```

Works just like I was looking for.

Comment: You can also get rid of the Grid.Row= dependency settings.

Comment: @kenny - you are right!  I thought that they were being used in some weird way, but they are not.  Thanks!  I have updated the answer.